# How to put command in ProjectExplorer menu in Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, contextmenu

How to put command in ProjectExplorer menu in Eclipse plugin? 
I mean rightclick context menu on file.
If I create example from wizard, it will make popup with action - but how can I do it with command?

Answer (score 0):

I think this [blog post](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/02/eclipse-rcp-tutorial-add-a-menu-item-to-the-popup-menu-when-right-click-a-file/) answers your question exactly.

But use Project Explorer id in menu contribution

```
<menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer">
```

instead of

```
<menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer">
```